# Kubuntu install to disk fails silently when opened

Tags: 16.04, system-installation, kubuntu, live-cd

I am running Kubuntu in live mode and there is an icon on the home desktop to "Install Kubuntu 16.04.1 LTS" however when I click it, it runs for a moment in the task bar and then silently goes away without opening a window or giving an error.

When running the install command from Konsole `ubiquity kde_ul` I get the error

> Bus error (core dumped)